# WinAutomation chrome extension (Softmotive)

Tags: windows, powershell, browser-automation

How can I make (Softmotive extension for browser automation) WinAutomationRuntimeWebHelper.exe run, or perhaps use automated process for activating this extension when its down? I was trying with IfService Action and never with any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made a error handling for "Failed to assume control of Chrome"

[image]

it rule is to run subflow fixChromeExtension which basically starts chrome with url: chrome://extensions, and then manually using keyboard input flips Softmotive switch to ON.

[image]

After this error handling process, initial process action is re-run, and viola, now it can take control of the browser.